# Saving a request variable inside foreach in Laravel store method

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

2 values are collected from the form as variables and rest as array. Then saving the values inside foreach loop in store method.

There is no problem with Array values, but for single variables, the values are showing null for the way I am trying.

I am trying to save *$start* and *$end* values inside the foreach loop. The code is below:

```
$start = $request->start;
$end = $request->end;

foreach ($request->user_id as $key => $val) {
  $bill = new UserBill;
    if (is_array($request->checked) && in_array($val, $request->checked)) {
       $bill->start = $start;
       $bill->end = $end;
       $bill->amount = $request->amount[$key];
       $bill->package = $request->package[$key];
       $bill->package_type = $request->package_type[$key];
       $bill->user_id = $val;
       $bill->save();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the information directly to the save method instead populating an object.

```
foreach ($request->user_id as $key => $val) {
  $bill = new UserBill;
    if (is_array($request->checked) && in_array($val, $request->checked)) {
       $bill->save([
            "start" => $request->start,
            "end" => $request->end,
            "amount" => $request->amount[$key],
            "package" => $request->package[$key],
            "package_type" => $request->package_type[$key],
            "user_id" => $val
       ]);
    }
}
```

Just make sure all the variables has content. You can check by using the dd() helper

```
dd($request->toArray()); //toArray() for an easier looking on the output
```

Comment: Tried, not working. The values inside foreach loop requires values in array. need to save the $start & $end value in array.

Comment: Can you please post the result of dd($request->toArray()); ?

Answer (score -2):

check your variables are declared in your model in the fillable part https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment , also try to put Log to see the values ​​of your variables:

```
Log::info($start)
Log::info($end)
```